# Solve the ODE $y(1+x^3)y'+x^2(1+y^2)=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the ODE $y(1+x^3)y'+x^2(1+y^2)=0$,

How do you solve this?

Separating and integrating I obtain:

$- \frac{1}{2} \ln(1+y^2) = \frac{1}{3} \ln(1+x^3) + C$,

Then exponentiating:
$(1+y^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}  }= (1+x^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} e^C$

And then:
$y^2=A(1+x^3)^{-\frac{2}{3}}-1$; $A=e^{-2C}$

I should then just root both sides for y and then there is the answer? I have looked at a solution online vastly different from mine and don't know why.

Note: the solution I saw is from wolfram

Comment: It is on wolfram I tried copying link but it doesn't save the equation I type in

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=e602dcdecb1843943960b5197efd3f2a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second anti-derivative should be $\frac13\ln|1+x^3|$ and in consequence $A=\pm e^C$ while $A=0$ gives the constant solution $y=0$, thus all $A\in\Bbb R$ are possible.

Everything else is correct. WA, as any CAS, sometimes does not find the "obviously" direct way, the tricks employed there are tuned towards always finding a solution in any case where a symbolic solution is possible.

Comment: In my opinion, *sometimes* is probably an understatement !